# How to create process in Windows ( C++ ) to run another section of code?

Tags: c++, windows, process, multiprocess

I am trying to create a process in a simple cpp program and want to run another section of code from a different source file in this process. I found the `CreateProcess` API for Windows that allows us to create processes but it seems like it only takes exe files for execution. Is there a way to create a process in windows and provide a function etc. to be executed by it similar to threads?

PS: I'm not looking for threads-based solutions since I want to test out a couple of things with processes and shared memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a process in windows and provide a function etc. to be executed by it similar to threads?

No. But what you can do is have your program run another copy of itself, passing it command line parameters to tell it what to do as needed. You can use `GetModuleFileName()` to get the full path to the EXE file of the current process. Then, in your `main()`/`WinMain()`, if any command line parameters are present, run the appropriate function and then exit, otherwise run your main logic normally.

Comment: Thanks for the work around. Although this solves my current purpose, I'm curious about how this is done in general. For instance, Chrome launches a couple more processes after the main process and the installation directory does not contain any exe files for the code to be run in these processes. I'm wondering if there is a way to replicate the same behavior.

Comment: @SuryaPrakash If you look at a process manager you'll probably find that chrome launches multiple copies of the same executable but with different command line parameters depending on the functionality required of them.

Comment: @SuryaPrakash Using command line parameters is the easiest way to send commands to new processes, but it is certainly not the only way. There are many IPC (inter-process communication) mechanisms available. But yes, they usually stem from using the same EXE file for each process to keep code management simple